# Xarray Pandas dayofyear producing incorrect dimensions with leap years

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-xarray

I am trying to aggregate hourly climate data to daily means for yearly files with xarray.  However, I'm separating them by 'Water year' instead of calendar year - which is from October 1st through September 30th.

When I try to use the 'groupby(.dayofyear)' method, it produces an incorrect 'dayofyear' dimension on water years where either the start or end date falls within an actual leap year.

For example, for water year 2000 (10/01/1999 - 09/30/2000), which spans a leap date, the resulting code produces a dayofyear dimension of size 365, instead of 366.  When doing water year 2001 (10/01/2000 - 09/30/2001), which does not span a leap date, it produces an incorrect dimension size of 366 instead of 365.

I'm sure I could build the arrays from scratch, but am hoping there is a built in function or other simple method to solve this problem.

```
new_array['TMEAN'] = d['T2'].groupby('XTIME.dayofyear').mean(dim='Time')
```

Comment: A [MWE](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports) would be helpful to help diagnose what is happening with `dayofyear`; however, ultimately I think [`resample`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.12.1/generated/xarray.DataArray.resample.html) might be a better fit for your needs (downsampling from hourly to daily frequency).  See examples [here](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/v0.12.1/time-series.html#resampling-and-grouped-operations).

Comment: @spencerkclark Thanks for the reply.  The resample function looks like it does exactly what I'd like it to.  However, 'XTIME' is a coordinate, not a dimension, and the 'Time' dimension is of 'Int64Index' format which throws the error 'TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index.'  Are you aware of a workaround ?

Comment: @spencerkclark Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer!  Effective solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing -- here is a short example of using `resample` to do this.  We'll first construct a DataArray that shares a similar structure to yours.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

ntimes = 24000
time = np.arange(ntimes)
times = xr.DataArray(pd.date_range('2000', periods=ntimes, freq='H'))
xtime = xr.DataArray(times, dims=['time'], coords=[time], name='XTIME')
da = xr.DataArray(np.random.random(ntimes), dims=['time'], coords=[time], name='T2')
da['XTIME'] = xtime
```

Here `da` is indexed by a dimension named `'time'`, with an integer coordinate.  It also has a datetime coordinate called `'XTIME'`:

```py
<xarray.DataArray 'T2' (time: 24000)>
array([0.285948, 0.046776, 0.0814  , ..., 0.47595 , 0.241202, 0.453325])
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 ... 23994 23995 23996 23997 23998 23999
    XTIME    (time) datetime64[ns] 1999-01-01 ... 2001-09-26T23:00:00
```

To use `resample`, we need to make `'XTIME'` a dimension coordinate in the DataArray instead of `'time'`.  A useful method for doing that is [`swap_dims`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.swap_dims.html):

```py
result = da.swap_dims({'time': 'XTIME'}).resample(XTIME='D').mean()
```

`result` then looks like:

```py
<xarray.DataArray 'T2' (XTIME: 1000)>
array([0.487798, 0.422622, 0.497371, ..., 0.487836, 0.500065, 0.482849])
Coordinates:
  * XTIME    (XTIME) datetime64[ns] 1999-01-01 1999-01-02 ... 2001-09-26
```

Then, if I understand things correctly, separating things into "water years" is just a matter of subsetting `result`, e.g.:

```py
water_year_2000 = result.sel(XTIME=slice('1999-10-01', '2000-09-30'))
```